# SocketIO/Mongoose JS .push to array issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, socket.io

This is using NodeJS, SocketIO, & Mongoose.

Client side button is firing server side 'LoadF' socket which is supposed to make 3 queries through mongoose and send back the results in the socket callback. I'm trying to push each of the Mongoose query results to an array that will be sent back as a single stringified JSON.

The problem is that .push isn't filling the 'doc' array. I think it might be a scope issue but I have tried every imaginable combo I can think of with no results.

Code (displaying just 1 of the 3 mongoose queries needed):

```
socket.on('loadF', function(data,callback){
        var doc = [];
        console.log("before:" + toString(doc));
        filldoc(function(err, assets){
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log("during:" + assets);
            doc.push(JSON.stringify(assets));
        });
        callback(doc.join(','));
        console.log("after:" + doc[0]);
        function filldoc(callback){
            initCm.find({}, function(err, assets){
                if (err) return callback(err, null);
                callback(null, assets[0]);
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the output I'm getting from the log with no errors:

```
before:[object Undefined]
after:undefined
during:{ _id: 54e4c934b61b8b6824ff38aa,
  id: 'document',
  version: '1.0',
  __v: 0 }
```

The 'during' output is displaying what should be put into the array.

Not sure why 'during' is coming after 'after' though? No matter what I try that always seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filldoc()` is asynchronous.  That means you can ONLY process the results it creates IN the callback that you provide it.   Your current location for these lines of code:

```
callback(doc.join(','));
console.log("after:" + doc[0]);
```

will run BEFORE filldoc has finished its work and called its callback and thus `doc` is still empty.  Instead, you need to move those inside of the callback like this:

```
socket.on('loadF', function(data,callback){
    var doc = [];
    console.log("before:" + toString(doc));
    filldoc(function(err, assets){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("during:" + assets);
        doc.push(JSON.stringify(assets));
        callback(doc.join(','));
        console.log("after:" + doc[0]);
    });

    function filldoc(callback){
        initCm.find({}, function(err, assets){
            if (err) return callback(err, null);
            callback(null, assets[0]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I see, thanks! 'initCm.find' is also asynchronous so I'm going to have to figure out how to get each of the 3 callbacks I need to store and read as 1 string. That's unrelated to this question though so I marked this as the correct answer. Thanks again.